# Closing script tag on IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

With this code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/resources/js/myscript.js"></script>
```

It works on the modern browsers  but when I try to execute the script on Internet Explorer 7 all the  tags are disappeared and its mandatory to work on ie7

Comment: Are you sure it's the html tag and not the actual script that is not compatible with IE7?

Comment: In any cases there's not enough here to answer the question

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Check the developer console. There's probably an error in the script.

Comment: Closing `script` tags are required in all browsers and always have been.  What's more likely is that the script you are referencing has code in it that is not backward compatible to IE7 and causing an error.

Comment: Try linking a dummy script with just an alert. Also, try removing the language tag, you don't need it, and I'm not sure you have it capitalized correctly.

Comment: The closing tap it's not on the code when you check it on the browser.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara In IE7, I believe the `language` attribute was still required. Even if it wasn't, that's not the problem.

Comment: @Scott Nah, even IE6 works without it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Perhaps, but as I said, that's not the issue.

Comment: No, even with IE6 neither the `language` nor the `type` was required for JavaScript code (and it still isn't; Crockford has been advising to leave it off for a long time).

Comment: @Poiny Native IE7 has no dev console.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara oh right; well it does report errors however (in its own inimitable way). You at least get the little warning icon, and it seems like there's a configuration option to make it always give an error popup. (I haven't had to worry about it in many years.)